# Use with mongodb $in only showing first id

Tags: php, mongodb

I am working on a project with mongodb and sphinx. I have sphinx results in an array. This is what the array looks like. 
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(33)
  [1]=>
  int(34)
}

33, 34

When I try to get the results from mongodb using $in only the first id is displayed. I am have been racking my head over this. I have looked at many examples that show how to do this, but the results are not correct. Here is the mongodb query that only returns the first id.

```
 $collection->find(array("_id" => array('$in' => array((int)$theseIds))));
```

Now, if I do 
`$collection->find(array("_id" => array('$in' => array((int)33,34))));`

I get the correct results. Not sure what is going on here. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you! :)

Comment: is `$theseIds` already an array, and in the first example you're embedding the array inside an array?

Comment: I got the variable $theseIds from imploding the array like this $theseIds = implode(', ', $itemIds); So, it is a comma separated list of numbers.

Comment: Then MongoDB is trying to find an `_id` that matches `"33,34"` for example. Why aren't you just passing (`'$in' => $itemIds`)?

Comment: Well when  I used ('$in' => $itemIds) I get the correct results. Thank you. You are awesome. Easy fix. :)